# mac os x lion configuration problem with gitosis

Tags: macos, git, osx-lion, gitosis

I'm trying to setup gitosis on my mac mini with mac os x lion (clean install).

Basically a followed [this guide](http://www.koushikdutta.com/2009/04/setting-up-gitosis-server-on-os-x.html)

I also looked at [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/124607/cant-clone-gitosis-admin-git-local-from-my-snow-leopard-server-running-gitosis)

If I try to clone the gitosis-admin.git repo i get the following error:

```
git clone git@127.0.0.1:gitosis-admin.git
Cloning into gitosis-admin...
Assertion failed: (argv0_path), function system_path, file exec_cmd.c, line 30.
error: git-shell died of signal 6
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I also tried to use localhost, the ip or the remote ip.

One thing i noticed, if i try to login as my git user (a standard mac user, without password) trough ssh i can't login (makes sens), but if I set a password I thought I should get an answer like

```
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
  Connection to gitserver closed.
```

but I can login like normal.

I've been searching for around a week, and a found no result in the internet with this error...

Edit:
One thing, I also installed gitosis on my macbook pro, following the same instructions and it worked! What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay strange, I figured out... Somehow I've to specify the complete path from the git user's home direcotry:

```
git clone git@host:repositories/gitosis-admin.git
```

with this command I can clone the directory